# Getting MODULEINFO internally

Tags: c++, c, winapi

How to get MODULEINFO of module that's inside my own exe?

```
  BOOL GetModuleInformation(
  HANDLE       hProcess,
  HMODULE      hModule,
  LPMODULEINFO lpmodinfo,
  DWORD        cb
);
```

needs PID so looks like it works only external way

Comment: Pas the `HANDLE` for your own process?

Comment: `GetCurrentProcess()`.    Note:  this is not C or C++.   It is the windows API.

Comment: As Peter says, hProcess is not a process ID, it's a handle to your process, which `GetCurrentProcess()` will provide.